# Read IP address from a text file in C

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have a text file(IP_CONFIG.txt) containing an IP address like this

```
CS  192.168.128.3
PORT    1111
```

i want to read the mentioned IP in the text file in my C code with a parameter. My code looks like this

```
<<header files>>
#define ROW 11
#define COL 2

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("IP_CONFIG.txt", "r");
    unsigned char IP_CS;
    int PORT_CS;
    unsigned char ip_list[ROW][COL];

    IP_CS = fscanf(f,"%s",&ip_list[0][2]);
    PORT_CS =  fscanf(f,"%d",&ip_list[1][2]);

    // I use this values in my program for configuring the server address
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_CS);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr("IP_CS");

    while(1)

    {
    //basic socket functions
    }

}
```

Here the program is getting compiled without any error but when i execute the program it is showing

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

can anyone tell why I am getting this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you assigning the results of `fscanf` to `IP_CS` and `PORT_CS`? `fscanf` returns the number of items that it read.

Comment: What is `inet_addr("IP_CS")` supposed to do? The argument to `inet_addr()` is supposed to be an address like `192.168.128.3`. Since you put `IP_CS` in quotes, it's just a string, not a variable.

Comment: Why are you not checking the result of fopen() before trying to use it to access a file?

Comment: Do you use an IDE? If not, why not? If you do, set a breakpoint at the start of this very small code and step through it line by line. When you get to the line which segfaults, it should be obvious what is wrong (and you can examine the value of your variables and see that one is NULL).  There, that's taught you how to fish. If you already new you would most likely not have needed to post a question here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for segmentation fault is accessing out-of-bound memory. With a definition of

```
#define ROW 11
#define COL 2

unsigned char ip_list[ROW][COL];
```

using

```
&ip_list[0][2]
```

is invalid because of [*off-by-one*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error. Indexing starts from `0` hence there is no 3rd element here.

Also, always check for the return value of `fopen()` before using the returned pointer.

Then, usage of `fscanf()` is wrong.

Next, `inet_addr("IP_CS");` I really don't have idea what this is supposed to do.

**Fix :**

A better approach will be

1. Read a complete line from file using `fgets()`
2. Tokenize based on delimiter space (change according to your need).
3. copy the token value reflecting the IP address to a `char` array.
4. convert the token to `int` in case of port number and put to another variable.
5. use them to populate `server_addr`.

Comment: There are so many other things wrong with his program. Good luck explaining them all.

Comment: @Barmar You're very right But i wanted to point to the major problem for segmentation fault. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Can you look at my updated answer !! and check the issue?? Thanks

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your quick expertised answer. Appriciate

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read a string into the character element i.e `ip_list[0][2]`.